# Javascript: Many conditions but different actions

Tags: javascript

I'm creating a BMI calculator.

This is my code so far:

```
var $ = function(id) {
    return document.getElementById(id);
}
var calculateBmi = function() {
var weight = parseInt($("weight").value);
var height = parseInt($("height").value);

    if (weight > 0 && height > 0 && weight !=isNaN && height !=isNaN){
    var bmi = Math.floor((weight / (height * height)) * 703);
    $("bmi_message").innerHTML = "" + bmi;
}

    if (bmi > 18.5) {
        $("bmi_message").innerHTML = ": Underweight";
        }
    else if (bmi >= 18.5 && bmi <= 24.9) {
        $("bmi_message").innerHTML = ": Normal";
        }
    else if (bmi >= 25 && bmi <= 29) {
        $("bmi_message").innerHTML = ": Overweight";
        }
    else if (bmi > 30) {
        $("bmi_message").innerHTML = ": Obese";
    }
    else if (isNaN(weight)) {
        $("weight_message").innerHTML = "Enter numerical weight value (lbs)";
    }
    else if (isNaN(height)) {
        $("height_message").innerHTML = "Enter numerical height value (kg)";
    }
    }
    window.onload = function () {
        $("calculateBmi").onclick = calculateBmi;
}
```

I have all these conditions (bmi > x OR bmi < x) that require different actions. Each range should result in a different text being displayed in my span element, however this is not happening. Could someone explain to me what is wrong and maybe provide me with better practices?

Comment: can you have a demo of your problem?

Comment: Shouldn't the first condition be `bmi < 18.5`?

Comment: @Barmar you are amazing. Sometimes another set of eyes makes the world of a difference

Answer (score 0):

In your code

```
if (bmi > 18.5) {
    $("bmi_message").innerHTML = ": Underweight";
    }
```

will always be true for any value higher than 18.5 so you wont get any other value but always Underweight.

Try

```
if (bmi < 18.5) {
    $("bmi_message").innerHTML = ": Underweight";
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

This only points out a third particular issue in your code. You are checking if weight (and height) are numbers with `weight != isNaN`, but:

```
100 != isNaN // --> true
'text' != isNaN // --> true
```

isNaN isn't a static value but a `function` to use like so:

```
var weight = 100; isNaN(weight) // -->false
                  !isNaN(weight) // --> true

var height = 'text'; isNaN(height) // --> true
                     !isNaN(height) // --> false
```

You should consider all three answers here together to get the right code.